# On entering in a TEdit, it is doubling the text inside of itself

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10-seattle

I am using Embarcadero® RAD Studio 10 Seattle Version 23.0.20618.2753. I just started making a Mobile App. I placed two `TEdit` controls on one `TForm`. They are

```pascal
Edit_FirstName: TEdit;
Edit_LastName: TEdit;
```

Now, when I am running this app on a mobile device and filling in my name, suppose I wrote `Michael` in the field `Edit_FirstName` and `Schumacher` in the field `Edit_LastName`. Up to this point, everything is OK.

But now, when I move back to the field `Edit_FirstName` and going to add `@` after `Michael`, it should be `Michael@` but instead it is becoming `MichaelMichael@`. The `TEdit` itself doubles the text which is already written inside of it, and then adds new characters after that.

It is a brand new Form project. I have not written a single line of code in this project.

The code is:

```pascal
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.Edit;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Edit_FirstName: TEdit;
    Edit_LastName: TEdit;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

end.
```

The fmx file is:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 414
  ClientWidth = 247
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object EDIT_FirstName: TEdit
    Touch.InteractiveGestures = [LongTap, DoubleTap]
    TabOrder = 2
    Position.X = 72.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 56.000000000000000000
  end
  object EDIT_LastName: TEdit
    Touch.InteractiveGestures = [LongTap, DoubleTap]
    TabOrder = 1
    Position.X = 72.000000000000000000
   Position.Y = 88.000000000000000000
  end
end
```

How do I fix this? Can anyone help me?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm having a hard time understanding what the actual problem is. Please show some actual code and examples of what you are seeing

Comment: Even though you haven't written any code, please include the `.fmx` file content in your post.

Comment: Submit your codeless project to Emba as a problem report.

Comment: Thank you for updating the question. Previously it was indeed very hard to understand what you meant, but now it is crystal clear. I cannot reproduce the issue in Delphi 10.3 on Windows 7, however.

Comment: There is two details I would like to know: 1) You referred earlier to a PEST option, what do you mean by that? 2) It would be good if you show what settings you have for the edit fields, and that is best seen from the `.fmx` file (or with the form view active, select `view as text` from the popup menu)

Comment: I also cannot reproduce this problem on Delphi 10.3 on Win10, so please add the contents of your .Fmx file to your q.  Please also explain **exactly** what you mean by "running this app in mobile ".

Comment: @TomBrunberg thanks for your interest in my problem.

Comment: @TomBrunberg thanks for your interest in my problem.  1)   Its PASTE not PEST i made mistake sorry for that. When i enter in any TEdit this option appears automatically.

Comment: @MartynA   Running this app means installed this single form as app in mobile to check y its behaving like this.

Answer (score 8):

This is a known issue, including:

[RSP-19742: TEdit is duplicating entered characters](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-19742)
(fixed in Rio)

[RSP-20493: TEdit / TMemo duplicating Letters when text recognition is on (Samsung VK)](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-20493)
(fixed in Rio)

`TEdit` has also had known issues with duplicating text when Enter or Backspace are typed, including:

[RSP-14495: [Android] TEdit duplicates initial input on some VKs after 'return' key is pressed](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-14495)
(fixed in Rio)

[RSP-17232: Duplicate words appear on pressing backspace in an FMX TEdit in android](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-17232)
(fixed in Tokyo Release 1)

[RSP-18478: Text are duplicated when press backspcae with Google Gboard](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-18478)
(fixed in Tokyo Release 2)